# subimport and includeonly

Tags: include, import

Say I have a document structured as follows.

```
main.tex
    + ch1
        - ch.tex
        - s1.tex
        - s2.tex
    + ch2
        - ch.tex
        - s1.tex
        - s2.tex
```

Here, `*.tex` are LaTeX files, and `ch1` and `ch2` are directories.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{import}
    \includeonly{ch1/ch}
\begin{document}
\subimport{ch1/}{ch}
\subimport{ch2/}{ch}
\end{document}

% ch1/ch.tex
\input{s1}
\input{s2}

% ch1/s1.tex
Section 1.1

% ch1/s2.tex
Section 1.2

% ch2/ch.tex
\input{s1}
\input{s2}

% ch2/s1.tex
Section 2.1

% ch2/s2.tex
Section 2.2
```

Unfortunately, this compiles the whole document, not just chapter 1. I'm probably doing this completely wrong, but I was trying to do the following. I have a separate folder for each chapter; in each chapter folder, I have a file `ch.tex` that manages the chapter as a whole, and files `s1.tex`, `s2.tex`,... that contain the major sections of the chapter. I am using the import command because I want to be able to use relative paths within `ch.tex` (both for inputing the section files, and for things like including graphics). However, in order to speed up compilation, I want to be able to use `\includeonly`. Is there a way to get the advantages of both `import` and `\includeonly`? What is the best practice for structuring large documents like this? (I'm curious about the best practice even if it means giving up relative paths or `includeonly`. Based on the other posts I read, it seems like the experts favor `include` instead of `import` [[How to use the import package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58465/how-to-use-the-import-package), [Splitting a large document into several files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/splitting-a-large-document-into-several-files?rq=1), [How to make "\input" in a "\include"-d file use the correct current path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52486/how-to-make-input-in-a-include-d-file-use-the-correct-current-path?rq=1) ] -- is there a good reason for this?) I saw a post ([Getting \includeonly functionality with import package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43347/getting-includeonly-functionality-with-import-package)) that I hoped would give me the answer, but that post ended up skirting the actual issue.

Comment: If `chX`are directories I'd simply use `\input{chX/sY.tex}` to include the sections. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the outline of a structure I've grown over the years.

Each chapter has a well named directory containing `contents.tex` and any other needed files for that chapter.

In my preamble, `macros.tex`:

```
% placeholders for commands often renewed
\newcommand{\here}{here}
\newcommand{\mychaptername}{whatever}
```

In the main driver, `book.tex`:

```
\include{macros}

%%-%%
%\includeonly{
%Preface/contents,
%FermiProblems/contents,
% ...
%}
%
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\here}{Preface}
\renewcommand{\mychaptername}{Preface}
\include{\here/contents}

\renewcommand{\here}{FermiProblems}
\renewcommand{\mychaptername}{Calculating on the Back of an Envelope}
\include{\here/contents}

 % and so on ...
```

Then, in a typical  `contents.tex`

```
% FermiProblems/contents.tex
%
\chapter{\mychaptername}
\label{\here}
% ...
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{\here/fermi_stamp.jpg}
% ...
\begin{mytikz}
\input{\here/carbonfootprint}
\end{mytikz}
% ...
```

Remembering to use `\here` for files referenced from `contents.tex` takes care of finding those files in the current directory.

Since there are only a dozen or so chapters and they change infrequently, cutting and pasting the three line block of code for each chapter is easier than writing a macro to do the job.

I've found this structure to be pretty robust. There's a lot more in my preamble, and adding even some complex functionality (writing selected material to other files for later compilation) can be managed from one place.

For a large project you're just beginning, I recommend wrapping some standard `LaTeX` constructs (e.g. the `mytikz` environment above) with your own macros, so that you can change their behavior later with less wizardry and hence fewer questions on this site.

**Edit:** To compile just one chapter, use the following driver in the chapter directory.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt]{book}

\input{../macros}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\here}{.}
\renewcommand{\mychaptername}{Test}
\include{\here/contents}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was more concerned with what happens with multiple \documentclass \begin{document} and \end{document} commands.  All of the following will run without errors except for preamble.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for example
\newcommand{\preambleflag}{}
\begin{document}% you can only do this once
```

Here is master.tex

```
\input{preamble}
\tableofcontents
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Here is chapter1.tex

```
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{preambleflag}%
{\input{preamble}%
 \edef\masterswitch{end}}%
{\edef\masterswitch{@gobble}}%
\chapter{I started life as a child}
yada yada yada
\csname \masterswitch\endcsname{document}%
```

And chapter2.tex is almost identical

```
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{preambleflag}%
{\input{preamble}%
 \setcounter{chapter}{1}% will be incrremented before use
 \edef\masterswitch{end}}%
{\edef\masterswitch{@gobble}}%
\chapter{I started life as a child}
yada yada yada
\csname \masterswitch\endcsname{document}%
```

You can use \include instead of \input for everything except the preamble.

The first \csname was just to avoid having to add \makeatletter \makeatother.  The last one was to avoid having anything appear after \end{document}.

Comment: Very interesting answer (I'm sad, that I discover it so late)! Do I correct understand, that particular chapter can be compiled individually (in its directory)? If this is true, how to manage paths to images, which I like to have stored in chapter sub directories?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152619/how-to-define-pathname-variables?s=1|2.0937