# Structuring a Large Document

Tags: cross-referencing, input

I just started to write my thesis and i want to organize my document in Latex using the `\input` command, so for example, the main file `main.tex` is like this:

```
    \begin{document}
       \input{chapter1}
    \end{document}
```

and `chapter1` have also nasted calls like this:

```
this chapter is devided into two main sections
    \input{firstsection}
    \input{secondsection}
```

besides, these sections have references to each others with `\ref` command and `Latex` could not resolve these references. I have read this [here](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~rdale/resources/writingnotes/latexstruct.html).

Is there a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: You have tried "2 The More Complex Method" with `\include`?

Comment: One potential disadvantage of this method is that, unlike \input, each included file will automatically begin on a new page.

Comment: Might you be able to work with an editor/front end that supports [code folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding)? That way, you don't need to keep track of lots of individual files and which one gets included or inputted by which.

Comment: @Massinissa: A chapter starts a new page anyway. Inside the included chapter file you can still use `\input`; `\include` cannot be nested. In opposite to `\input`, the references, table of contents, ... remain more or less intact, if an `\include` file is excluded from compiling, because the auxiliary data of the `\include` file are kept in a separate `.aux` file.

Comment: the linked file was "last significantly updated" in 1993.  thus it was intended for use with an earlier (now obsolete) version of latex.  many things have improved since then, not least of which is the available documentation.

Comment: cross references will work if the file is as you show, the comment in the linked file is that a reference to section 1 will fail if you have commented out section 1.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/subimport-and-includeonly/123096#123096. Cross references between files will work.

Comment: References doesn't work? It is impossible. The LaTeX's `\input` expands to primitive `\input` and it realizes only one input stream independent of the file. Macros for references cannot distinguish what file is currently open and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was having the same problem as you a year ago, I can tell you ---after some intensive research--- that the best you can do is use `\include` for your chapters and `\input` for other codes (I'm specially thinking of `TikZ` here), sections, subsections, etc.

As stated in the comments, you are going to use a new page for every chapter, so that should be the end of the discussion with `\include` and chapters.  Using `\include` here should be a plus, since it allows you to `\includeonly` the chapters you want to edit, leaving behind all the other ones that you are not currently working on.  Now, since `\include`s can't be nested, you should consider using `\input`s for your writing within each of these `\include`.

`\input` is specially useful for, say, `Tikz` pictures, or any code that should be easier to read the file's name instead of the whole thing; specially if once you have set it right, you don't want to mess it around anymore.

For starting writing, I **strongly** recommend one of the **BEST** books for thesis in `LaTeX` I have ever read: *`Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis`* by Nicola Talbot, available [here](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/).