# How is \input used?

Tags: macros, input

I'm trying to input a separate file, `chapter1.tex`, into the `mainbody.tex` file. So in the `mainbody.tex` file I'm typing,

```
\documentclass[...]{book}
\blah
\blah 

\begin{document}
\input{\...\chapter1.tex}
\end{document}
```

Both files, `chapter1.tex` and `mainbody.tex`, are scripted with the same preamble. When I compile `chapter1.tex` the process ends without an error and the  `.pdf` document is properly generated. But when I compile the `mainbody.tex` it gives me

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

and it is referring to the `chapter1.tex` file.

It seems that, as the `main body.tex` is being compiled, when the compiler reaches the `\input` command, it reads the preamble of the `chapter1.tex` file and it recognizes its commands, as commands of the main body of the `mainbody.tex` file, thus gives the error.

However, a `mainbody.pdf` file do generate even if the compiling process ends with an error.

Any idea of what causes the error and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The backslash starts command/macro names and `\chapter` is interpreted as chapter command. This problem can be avoided by using the slash for path names: `\input{/.../chapter1.tex}`. The slash also works in the case of Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in fact inputting the preamble code twice - the second time after `\begin{document}`. So leave it out of `chapter1.tex`. If you need to compile chapter 1 separately, make a new main, or use `\include` and `\includeonly` in the main you have.

You may find this workflow template useful:
[subimport and includeonly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/subimport-and-includeonly/123096#123096)