# include a Table of contents in a separate abstract of the book

Tags: table-of-contents, article

I want to write an abstract of my thesis. So I started an article class document (to be precise I'm using the following : `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,showkeys]{revtex4}`, because I like the `revtex4` output).

I finished to write the abstract, but then I thought it will be better to include the full table of contents and the bibliography. What do you think is the best way to do so. If there isn't any easy method, I'm ok to do this manually, but then can you give me the template for this knowing that my thesis contains Parts, chapters, sections, and subsections.

Edit :

I have **fulltext.tex** that contains the actual contents of the thesis (report document class).

Then I have **abstruct.tex** this file contain only a summary of the thesis, there are no contents in here, just the title and the summary. My question is to include the TOC and the bibliography too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,showkeys]{revtex4}
\begin{document}
\title{verry interesting title}
\thanks{verry interesting footnote}
\author{{\footnotesize A. author}}  
\keywords{verry interesting keywords } 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schweinebacke But I don't have any content in this file besides the abstract. The actual thesis is in a separate file with a report class document.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Please let me know if this needs more clarification.

Comment: I think you want to have all the source (abstract and full text) in just one file. Then you can compile just the abstract and toc and bibliography with a switch. `includeonly` will probably help. I may find time later to provide an actual answer fleshing out this comment. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/subimport-and-includeonly/123096#123096

Comment: Why do you need to combine a document written in the `report` class with a document written using `revtex4`. That sounds a bit strange, especially when `revtex4` is specifically intended for journal articles, not thesis’s

Comment: If you'd use the same class, you could input `fulltext.toc` in `abstract.tex` (you would need additional commands like `\makeatletter`, but it could be done). But `revtex4` makes a lot of things different than the standard classes so you would have to define a lot of extra commands. This would be a lot of extra work only for the abstact document. An alternative would be to use `pdfpages` to include the table of contents pages from `fulltext.pdf`. But I would use either a single document or at least the same classes.

Comment: OK. Thank you all. What about doing things manually. I will type all the table of contents. I still need some help for the layout, can you provide a template for this.