# Is my current workflow worth using or idiotic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, workflow

I am currently writting my thesis and use several graphics which I make using tikz. For now on my workflow/document looks as the following:

In the latex project folder I have a seperate folder where I store all my .tex files which contains the drawings.

So for example:

- business_model_overview.tex
- distribution_of_findings.tex
- ...

I then include these files in the main latex_file just by using the \include option.

The tikz files mentioned above are created  capsulated either using Tikz_EDT or QTikz.

I nowstarted to rearranging my worklfow as I swapped using Kile as Editor instead of Overleaf as before. I heared about the standalone_package I did not use till now.

Simple qeustion: Would the use of the standalone package could make my life/workflow easier in any form?
Is my current workflow okay or did you see some aspects for improvement as I can adjust now before starting over.
[ One downward as I see till now could be that every time I recompile each picture must be compiled again. But not sure if this is really so bad. ]

Many thanks in advacne for suggestions.

Comment: I actually use always the `standalone` class for creating `TikZ` pictures ('cause so I can see more details and so on), but your way of doing TeX (or writing your thesis) isn't bad. I can tell only for me: I would do it exactly that way (but I wouldn't use an external `TikZ` editor for creating pictures, as you mentioned it is better to use the `standalone` package …).

Comment: You're using `\include` for those pictures? That is not good, as `\include` does a `\clearpage`,  `\input` seems like the reasonable thing to do for pictures (if they shouldn't be made standalone).

Comment: My workflow for documents with many Ti*k*Z graphics differs quite a lot. I'll create a write-up (using GNU make).

Comment: @Skillmon sorry that was my fault, I look it up and you were right, I use \input rather than \include

Comment: Not directly applicable but possibly helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123058/subimport-and-includeonly/123096#123096

Comment: I usually just put all TikZ code (and pgfplots, and minted, etc. etc.) directly in the main tex file. This saves a lot of trouble organizing files and compile sequences. The compilation is sufficiently fast to prevent that being an issue. And if you use an editor with code folding it doesn't clutter the view of the source. For my thesis I did organize a little bit: one file per chapter, with conditional compilation, which essentially resulted in working on each chapter and compiling it as if it was a single document.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So as promised in the comments, here is my current setup for image-heavy documents using Ti*k*Z and similar (the below uses Ti*k*Z, `circuitikz`, includes SVGs, plots created with Python and possibly other images):

I maintain a shared preamble for all `standalone` TeX creations (like those of Ti*k*Z and `circuitikz` images) to sync stuff like font sizes and other stuff related to design. Additionally there is a shared preamble for every Ti*k*Z picture and a shared one for the `circuitikz` stuff.

For my latest work the shared preamble only includes

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

the one dedicated to all ordinary Ti*k*Z pictures is in fact empty and the one for all the `circuitikz` images contains

```
\usepackage[european,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
```

For every image I can now create a file which contains only a `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and the contents in between (additional preamble material for that file could be added here, too). `circuitikz` image code is saved as `img/<filename>.circuit`, ordinary Ti*k*Z pictures as `img/<filename>.tikz`.

The next thing to setup is a Makefile for the main document and another Makefile for all those images.

The main Makefile for my latest project looks like this:

```
# User defined variables {{{
##########################################
# engine to be used
TEX    = pdflatex
# flags for that engine
FLAGS  = -halt-on-error -8bit
# relative path to included TeX-files
TEXF   = ./tex
# relative path to included TeX-files containing only preamble stuff
PREF   = ./preamble
# relative path to img folder containing tikz and circuit files
IMGF     = ./img
##########################################
# }}}
# Automatically defined variables {{{
##########################################
FILE   = $(wildcard ./*.tex)
SFILES = $(wildcard $(TEXF)/*.tex)
PREAMB = $(wildcard $(PREF)/*.tex)
PREAMB += $(wildcard $(PREF)/*.sty)
PREAMB += $(wildcard ./*.sty)
NAME   = $(FILE:%.tex=%)
OUT    = $(NAME).pdf
FMT    = $(NAME).fmt
##########################################
# }}}
# default target {{{
## the name 'quick' maybe misleading! 'all' might be faster if $(FILE) hasn't
## changed. 'quick' is for quickly running TeX assuming that you know what
## you're doing
quick: $(FMT) img
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) -fmt="$(NAME)" $(FILE)
    #$(TEX) $(FLAGS) $(FILE);
# }}}
all: img $(OUT) #bib
$(OUT): $(FILE) $(SFILES) $(PREAMB)# {{{
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) $(FILE);
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) $(NAME).tex > /dev/null;
    $(TEX) $(FLAGS) $(NAME).tex > /dev/null;
# }}}
$(FMT): $(FILE) $(PREAMB)# {{{
    $(TEX) -ini -enc -jobname="$(NAME)" "&$(TEX)" mylatexformat.ltx """$(FILE)"""
# }}}
img: # {{{
    cd $(IMGF); make -j4
# }}}
.PHONY: clean cleantex cleansubfoldertex quick all img clean_img
clean: cleantex cleansubfoldertex clean_img
cleantex: # {{{
    -rm $(shell find $(NAME)\.* | grep -Ev '\.tex$$' | grep -Ev '\.sty$$' | grep -Ev '\.bib$$')
# }}}
cleansubfoldertex: # {{{
    -cd $(TEXF); rm $(shell cd $(TEXF); find * | grep -v tex);
# }}}
clean_img: # {{{
    -cd $(IMGF); make clean
# }}}
```

This Makefile has the default target quick, which will build a custom format if something in `./preamble/` or the main file has changed, call the Makefile for the images with the option `-j4` which means that that Makefile can run 4 processes in parallel and build the PDF. It assumes that there is only one file with the file extension `.tex` which is the main file of the project.

The other targets are:

- `all`: running TeX three times (and building the images if necessary)
- `clean`: calling `cleantex`, `cleansubfoldertex` and `clean_img`
- `cleantex`: delete every file having the same name as the main file, except those having the file extensions `.tex`, `.sty` and `.bib`
- `cleansubfoldertex`: delete *all* files in `./tex/` except those containing `tex` in their names or file extension
- `clean_img`: call the img Makefile with `clean`

The second Makefile should be placed in the `./img/` sub folder. It defines the rules to build the different image file types.

```
# User defined variables {{{
##########################################
# engine to use for everything that needs TeX
TEX     = pdflatex
# flags for the TeX engine
TFLAG   = -halt-on-error
# Python call
PY          = python
# flags for python
PFLAG   = 
# inkscape call (used for conversion of svg to pdf)
INK         = inkscape
# flags for inkscape
IFLAG   = --without-gui
# output option for inkscape
IOOPT   = --export-pdf=
# relative path to included TeX-files containing preamble stuff
# circuit related preamble
CPREAMB = circuit_preamble.tex
# tikz related preamble
TPREAMB = tikz_preamble.tex
# shared preamble
MPREAMB = ct_preamble.tex
# a configuration file for python
PYCONF  = custom_rcParams.py
# file extensions of different files
# for the tikz pictures
TIKZ    = tikz
# for circuitikz pictures
CIRC      = circuit
# for plots created by python
PYPL        = plot.py
# for svg files
SVG         = svg
##########################################
# }}}
# Automatically defined variables {{{
##########################################
CFILES   = $(wildcard ./*.$(CIRC))
PFILES   = $(wildcard ./*.$(PYPL))
SFILES   = $(wildcard ./*.$(SVG))
TFILES   = $(wildcard ./*.$(TIKZ))
COUT     = $(CFILES:%.$(CIRC)=%.$(CIRC).pdf)
POUT     = $(PFILES:%.$(PYPL)=%.$(PYPL).pdf)
SOUT     = $(SFILES:%.$(SVG)=%.$(SVG).pdf)
TOUT     = $(TFILES:%.$(TIKZ)=%.$(TIKZ).pdf)
##########################################
# }}}

all: circuit pypl svg tikz
circuit: $(COUT)
pypl: $(POUT)
svg: $(SOUT)
tikz: $(TOUT)

%.$(CIRC).pdf: %.$(CIRC) $(CPREAMB) $(MPREAMB)
    $(TEX) $(TFLAG) -jobname="$<" "\input{$(MPREAMB)}\input{$(CPREAMB)}\input{$<}"
    -rm $<.aux
    -rm $<.log

%.$(TIKZ).pdf: %.$(TIKZ) $(TPREAMB) $(MPREAMB)
    $(TEX) $(TFLAG) -jobname="$<" "\input{$(MPREAMB)}\input{$(TPREAMB)}\input{$<}"
    -rm $<.aux
    -rm $<.log

%.$(PYPL).pdf: %.$(PYPL) $(PYCONF)
    $(PY) $(PFLAG) $<

%.$(SVG).pdf: %.$(SVG)
    $(INK) $(IFLAG) $< $(IOOPT)"$<.pdf"

.PHONY: all circuit pypl svg tikz clean clean_tikz clean_circuit clean_pypl clean_svg

clean: clean_tikz clean_circuit clean_pypl clean_svg

clean_circuit:
    -rm $(COUT)
clean_tikz:
    -rm $(TOUT)
clean_pypl:
    -rm $(POUT)
clean_svg:
    -rm $(SOUT)
```

All the PDFs created by it have the naming scheme `<filename>.<type>.pdf`, so every Ti*k*Z picture which's source was named `<filename>.tikz` will create a PDF named `<filename>.tikz.pdf`. This way the `clean` target knows which PDFs can be removed and you can distinguish the files and use different `\includegraphics` options based on the filename.

One important thing left to do is setting up `graphicx` to recognize those image files as PDFs. This is done with

```
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.circuit.pdf}{pdf}{*}{}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tikz.pdf}{pdf}{*}{}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.plot.py.pdf}{pdf}{*}{}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.svg.pdf}{pdf}{*}{}
```

Now you can include your Ti*k*Z picture with `\includegraphics{img/<filename>.tikz.pdf}`.

Running `make` in the directory of your main file should build everything necessary for your finished PDF.

The overall approach keeps a clean structure with distinctive names for different types of content.

## Possible speed gains

The above method builds really quick, as it parallelizes as much as possible (if you have many cores in your machine, you can change the `-j4` option to more processes). Further speed gains could be achieved with building formats for the Ti*k*Z and `circuitikz` files.

## Stuff to add

The project I used this on was a formulary for an exam, so I didn't need any bibliography or index. These should be added to the main Makefile if you need those (and shouldn't be too hard to do).

Comment: Wow, many thanks for the detailed description of your way handling pictures with tikz. I will have a try in using some aspects :)